# TypeError: fit_generator() got multiple values for argument 'steps_per_epoch'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train keras model. Below is the function for train model.

```
def train_model(input_videos, video_label, mapping, micro_expressions, val_x=None, val_micro=None, val_y=None, return_best=False):
    print("train_model")
    input_videos = np.asarray(input_videos)
    data_x, data_y, data_mapping, data_micro = H1_preprocessing(input_videos, video_label, mapping, micro_expressions)
    model, callbacks_lst = build_model()
    print("data_x: ", data_x.shape)
    print("data_y: ", data_y.shape)
    if val_x is not None and val_y is not None and val_micro is not None:
        hist = model.fit_generator([data_x, data_micro[0], data_micro[1], data_micro[2]], data_y, steps_per_epoch = 2, epochs = 20, verbose = 2, callbacks = callbacks_lst, validation_data=([val_x, val_micro[0], val_micro[1], val_micro[2]], val_y), use_multiprocessing=True, shuffle=True)
        print(hist) 
    else:
        hist = model.fit_generator([data_x, data_micro[0], data_micro[1], data_micro[2]], data_y, steps_per_epoch = 2, epochs = 20, verbose = 2, callbacks = callbacks_lst, use_multiprocessing=True, shuffle=True)
        print(hist)

    if return_best:
        print("Applying weights")
        model.load_weights("weights.best.hdf5")
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

The fit_generator() function creates error. I am not aware of providing right parameters at right position. It shows the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "concatenated_classifier.py", line 697, in <module>
    trained_model = train_model(list_gray_train_videos, list_train_label, clips_mapping, micro_expressions, None, None, None, True)
  File "concatenated_classifier.py", line 613, in train_model
    hist = model.fit_generator([data_x, data_micro[0], data_micro[1], data_micro[2]], data_y, steps_per_epoch = 2, epochs = 20, verbose = 2, callbacks = callbacks_lst, use_multiprocessing=True, shuffle=True)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: fit_generator() got multiple values for argument 'steps_per_epoch'
```

Suggest me where to provide steps_per_epoch and data_y.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `fit_generator` is `steps_per_epoch`. See the documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model

```py
fit_generator(
    generator, steps_per_epoch=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None,
    validation_data=None, validation_steps=None, validation_freq=1,
    class_weight=None, max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False,
    shuffle=True, initial_epoch=0
)
```

Therefore, when you call it like:

```py
hist = model.fit_generator(
    [data_x, data_micro[0], data_micro[1], data_micro[2]],
    data_y,
    steps_per_epoch=2,
    ...
)
```

You are providing `data_y` as a positional argument for this parameter and also supplying it as a keyword argument.

Note that `model.fit` now also supports generators, so this method is deprecated.

Comment: I used fit method now. I got an error that the input shape is not compatible with the model layers. data_x shape is (117,33,60,40,1), data_y is (117,2) data_micro is (13,117,1,1,1). In model, the input_1 layer is of (None,33,60,40), input_2, input_3, input_4 is (None,13,1,1,1). How should I resize data_micro, so that it will be compatible with model? The error is ValueError: Input 1 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None,13,1,1,1), found shape=(None,1,1,1).